# Using slots and signals to connect two forms in Qt

Tags: qt

Hi i am a newbie to Qt and started learning about slots and signals.

Here is a small program that I am testing with.
It contains two forms (MainWindow) and (form1).

MainWindow has a button and a label:

- If the button is clicked it shows form1, which has a button and a line edit.
- If this button (form1) is clicked it is supposed to take the string of the lineEdit and change the label of the mainwindow to be that string.

When testing it it doesn't work as intended, but I don't know why

MainwWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "form1.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    form1 *sender;
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void changelabel(QString);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form1.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    sender = new form1;
    connect(sender,SIGNAL(entered(QString)),this,SLOT(changelabel(QString)));
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    form1 formno1;
    formno1.setModal(true);
    formno1.exec();
}

void MainWindow::changelabel(QString x)
{
    ui->label->setText(x);
}
```

form1.h

```
#ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class form1;
}

class form1 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit form1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~form1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

signals:
    void entered(QString);

private:
    Ui::form1 *ui;
};

#endif // FORM1_H
```

form1.cpp

```
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"

form1::form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

form1::~form1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void form1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString name = ui->lineEdit->text();
    emit entered(name);
    this->hide();
}
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create absolutely new instance of your form, but your connection works only with another instance(sender) so use sender or do new connection with new instance. Try next for example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sender->setModal(true);
    sender->exec();//or show()
}
```

To avoid another errors in future I suggest you to write your code in constructor after `setupUi()`

Comment: Thanks alot. I got it now